# I have 2 network adapters in my Windows 10. Chrome is using ipv4 from one adapter and ipv6 from the other

Tags: networking

Title says it.

I have 2 network adapters, one eth0 (adapter1) and another is Wifi (adapter2).

When I have both network adapters enabled, start chrome and go to whatismyipaddress, it shows me the ipv4 from adapter1 and ipv6 from adapter2. If I turn off adapter 2, and refresh, it shows ipv4 from adapter1 and ipv6 from adapter1.

Both adapters have ipv4 and ipv6, but I don't understand why chrome is mixing ipv4 and ipv6 protocols from the 2 network cards.

Is there a way to control or fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I do not have an answer to the question of how to control/fix this behavior, but I find the attribution to Chrome unlikely. This sounds more like an OS-level routing problem than an application problem. Which OS is the question about? Also, do you actually need to connect both network adapters at the same time?

Comment: This is an OS issue.  Chrome doesn't know how many adapters you have nor what their IP addresses are.

Comment: It's windows 10. I already assigned different metrics to the adapters. One with metric 10 (lower priority) in ipv4 and ipv6 and the other with metric 5 (higher priority) in ipv4 and ipv6 but still I get them mixed up in CHrome .. weird